# Xamarin android C# class is not generated for jar library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I am trying to create xamarin android binding for this library [Android POS Print SDK](http://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/english/support/download/printer/sdk/CSJAndroidSDK_V118E.zip). It generates C# classes fine except this one ESCPOSPrinter. This is main class that does all the job. But it is not generated, though it exist in api.xml. Can you advice what can be the problem and how to make it generate this class so i can use it in Xamarin App?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the build warning, I would expect at least one of them references `ESCPOSPrinter` and the root reason that it is not included.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes there is warning "Class Com.Citizen.Sdk.ESCPOSPrinter has unknown base type com.citizen.csjposlib.c.c". Android app sample works with this jar file without any issues. Where can i find this dependency?

Comment: Inside jar file there is folder csjposlib. Do i need to reference it in xamarin somehow?

Comment: That class is probability in the same `.jar`, check the `api.xml` to determine the inheritance tree and see of one of the superclasses' visibility is not public, etc...

Comment: I checkied api.xml file and here is how looks this class there
<class abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" extends="com.citizen.csjposlib.c.c" extends-generic-aware="com.citizen.csjposlib.c.c" final="false" name="ESCPOSPrinter" static="false" visibility="public">
<constructor deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="ESCPOSPrinter" static="false" type="com.citizen.sdk.ESCPOSPrinter" visibility="public">
</constructor>
</class>

Comment: it cant find com.citizen.csjposlib.c.c and that is why dont generate this class. What can i do to help it find it?

Comment: All lower case Java class name (`com.citizen.csjposlib.c.c`), flag those classes as `name="obfuscated">false</attr>`